# Current System Time - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to get the current system time only in SQL Server / any database.

The date is not required...only the current time is required.

Comment: Please have a look [Get Date and Time From Current DateTime](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/09/12/sql-server-get-date-and-time-from-current-datetime-sql-in-sixty-seconds-025-video/)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `getdate()` or `current_timestamp`

This will give you both date and time but then you can format it however you need.

If you are using SQL Server 2008+ you can even format the result as `time`:

```
 select cast(getdate() as time)
```

If you are not in SQL Server 2008+, then you can use many [different methods](http://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/) to get the time only including:

```
 SELECT convert(char(8), getdate(), 108)
```

See [SQL fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/6569)  with several versions

Answer (score 0):

```
Using `getdate()` like:
    select getdate()
=============================

and get only time use convert function with 108 code like :
  select convert(varchar,GETDATE(),108)
```

Answer (score 0):

select CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE(),108) CurrTime;

Answer (score 0):

There is 3 different statement available to get the current system time

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),getDate(),108)

select CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),{fn NOW()},108)

select CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,108)
```

They all produce the same results and performance are the same, therefore it is really whatever one of the three you prefer the look of.